# How to load multiple templates with HandlebarJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, templates, handlebars.js

I am currently building a small Handlebars.js application. I have no prior experience and as I'm learning as I'm going along, I've been running in to a few issues.

My first issue is loading templates.

Currently I have functions like this for every single template I need to load

```
var populateDocs = function() {
   var srcContent = $( '#docs-template' ).html(),
        contentTemplate = Handlebars.compile( srcContent ),
        htmlContent = contentTemplate( content.getItem( 'docs' ) );

        $( '#docs' ).append( htmlContent );
};
```

I am reading templates from a content.json file so once this file is ready, I call multiple functions to populate each template.

```
content.onReady(
    function() {
        populateFooter();
        populateHomework();
        populateDocs();
        populateContact();
        generateTabs();
    }
);
```

My question is. Is there a way I can load all these templates without having to call each function for each template?

Answer (score 1):

I rather think the best you can do is to proceduralise things better.

If all the `populateXxx()` functions follow the same pattern as `populateDocs()` (or can be made to do so), then you can write :

```
var populate = function(id) {
    $('#'+id).append(Handlebars.compile($('#'+id+'-template').html())(content.getItem(id)));
};

content.onReady(function() {
    populate('footer');
    populate('homework');
    populate('docs');
    populate('contact');
    generateTabs();
});
```

or

```
content.onReady(function() {
    ['footer', 'homework', 'docs', 'contact'].forEach(populate);
    generateTabs();
});
```